# in a trivial space, every sequence converges for every element

Tags: general-topology

I appreciate if anyone can help me with find an example or a demonstration for:
"In a trivial space, every sequence converges to every element"
thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

The topological space $X$ is trivial if its only open sets are $\emptyset$ and $X$.  Now look at the definition of convergence of a sequence in a topological space...